# Inherit variable from superclass

Tags: python, oop

Let's assume I have two classes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class First():

        glob = 'Global data'

        def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
                self.arg1 = arg1
                self.arg2 = arg2
                print (arg1, arg2)

class Second(First):
        def __init__(self):
                print (self.glob)
```

And they are called from script as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import classes

data1 = 'First data part'
data2 = 'Second data part'

inst1 = classes.First(data1, data2)
inst2 = classes.Second()
```

This works, OK:

```
$ ./script.py
('First data part', 'Second data part')
Global data
```

I want to make `arg1` and `arg2` in `First` class something 'global', and use then it in `Second`:

```
class Second(First):
        def __init__(self):
                print (self.glob, self.arg1, self.arg2)
```

How I can achieve it?

Comment: You are confusing *instance* data with *class data*. The attributes you set in the `__init__` of `First` are per-instance attributes; instances of another class (even a subclass) won't see those. What values would instances of `Second` ever have for those attributes?

Comment: You will have to call `First.__init__` yourself (since you are overriding it in the child class), possibly via the `super` function.  After this super call, you will have access to those attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class First(object):

    glob = 'Global data'

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        #print (arg1, arg2)

class Second(First):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Second, self).__init__(*args)
        print (self.glob, self.arg1, self.arg2)

data1 = 'First data part'
data2 = 'Second data part'

inst1 = First(data1, data2)
inst2 = Second(data1, data2)
```

Comment: I think the OP question was python3 (just a guess)

Comment: `super` - seems what I need... Thanks, don't know about it.

Comment: @setevoy if you want to use fields of the parent class you need to call parent `__init__`

Comment: @Andrey yep, I understood... Tried do same with direct call `First(data1, data2)` inside `__init__` of `Second` :-)

Comment: Btw - it also works: `First.__init__(self, *args)`;
but seems this is incorrect way...

Answer (score 1):

The **init** of First is overloaded by Second, call the one of your parent class from your Second class

```
class Second(First):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Second, self).__init__("argument1", "argument2")
        print (self.glob, self.arg1, self.arg2)
```

In python3 it is like this:

```
class Second(First):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("argument1", "argument2")
        print (self.glob, self.arg1, self.arg2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unpacking](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments) in your `First` class `__init__()` method:

```
class First:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        for data in args:
            print(data)

# in your child class, you need to call First.__init__(), via super()

class Second(First):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Second, self).__init__(*args)  # pass args to First.__init__()
```

Usage:

```
import classes

i = Second("data", "data1", "data2", "data3")
```

Using unpacking allow your class to accept any number of arguments and will make writing subclasses faster and easier. Depending on your use case, it will sometimes better to use dictionnary unpacking, especially if you want named arguments:

```
class First:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs): # note the double wildcards here
        print(kwargs.get('data1'))
        print(kwargs.get('data2'))

class Second(First):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Second, self).__init__(**kwargs) 

# usage

i = Second(data1="something", data2="something else", another_arg="Yahoo")
```